# Transposing homeomorphism $S^1 \land S^1 \to S^1 \land S^1$ is a reflection of $S^2$

Tags: algebraic-topology, circles, homotopy-theory, spheres

Consider the smash product $S^1_1 \land S^1_2$ of two copies of circles, and let $f:S_1^1 \land S_2 ^1 \to S_2^1 \land S^1_1$  be the homeomorphism transposing the two factors. Since $S^1 \land S^1$ is homeomorphic to the sphere $S^2$, we can view $f$ as a map of $S^2$. Hatcher says that in this view, $f$ is a reflection of $S^2$ and therefore has degree $-1$. Is there a way to see this?

Comment: If you have an explicit homeomorphism $\varphi\colon S^1 \wedge S^1 \to S^2$ you could write out the composition $\varphi\circ f\circ \varphi^{-1}$ and see what it looks like

Comment: View $S^n$ as the one-point compactification $(\mathbb{R}^n)_+$. Then the map is $(\mathbb{R}^1_1)_+\wedge(\mathbb{R}^1_2)_+=(\mathbb{R}^1_1\oplus\mathbb{R}^1_2)_+\rightarrow  (\mathbb{R}^1_2\oplus\mathbb{R}^1_1)_+= (\mathbb{R}^1_2)_+\wedge(\mathbb{R}^1_1)_+$, where the middle map is induced by the linear map on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which interchanges coordinates. The linear map has determinant $-1$, which is therefore also the degree of the induced map on $(\mathbb{R}^2)_+$(check winding numbers).

Answer (score 3):

We get $S^1 \times S^1$ by attaching a 2-cell along the glue pattern $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$. When we transpose the factors, the boundary of the 2-cell gets wrapped $bab^{-1}a^{-1}$ along the wedge of $a$ and $b$. This is the same as if we first reflected the boundary and then rotated by 90 degrees. The map on the entire 2-cell can be described in the same way, each concentric circle is reflected and then rotated by 90 degrees. So when we quotient out by the wedge of $a$ and $b$, the map we get is a reflection followed by a 90 degree rotation. Since a rotation is homotopic to the identity and a reflection across 1-axis is degree -1, the overall degree is $-1$.