# A homotopy equivalence of $X \wedge Y \to Y \wedge X$ to itself.

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectra

In the Adams Bluebook, to define a smash product of CW-spectra, the author uses a homotopy equivalence between two smash product of compactly generated pointed spaces from $S^{1} \wedge Y$ to $Y \wedge S^{1}$ by $(t,x) \mapsto (x,-t)$. Why this sign change happen? If you think it is a basic question, so could you give me a reference?

Comment: Perhaps this is relevant https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3518569/transposing-homeomorphism-s1-land-s1-to-s1-land-s1-is-a-reflection-of

Comment: @ConnorMalin That is exactly what I want to find. Thank you very much!